# it's possible had 3 inserts in one sentence on mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I was wondering if it's possible to do this:

```
INSERT INTO capacitacion .pedido (fecha, total, folio) 
VALUES ( ? , ? , ?) 
AND 
INSERT INTO capacitacion.articulo (precio, descripcion, codigoBarras) 
VALUES (?,?,?) 
AND 
INSERT INTO capacitacion.pedidodetalle (pedidoId, articuloId, cantidad,subtotal) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?);
```

And all using one cicle for inside one class?

Comment: Based on your questions, you need to learn the [JDBC Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html). Si necesitas apoyo, contactame via chat.

Answer (score 2):

No, you must use multiple insert statements.

You can however add multiple rows to a table with one insert statement using the below example:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES(val1,val2,val3),(val4,val5,val6),(val7,val8,val9);
```

I know you will not end up using this, but here you can see an insert of 3 rows into the table '`table`' with the values presented above

Answer (score 0):

No, not in that syntax, You'd have to do something along the lines of:

```
"INSERT INTO capacitacion .pedido (fecha, total, folio) VALUES ( ? , ? , ?); INSERT INTO capacitacion.articulo (precio, descripcion, codigoBarras) VALUES (?,?,?); INSERT INTO capacitacion.pedidodetalle (pedidoId, articuloId, cantidad,subtotal) VALUES (?,?,?,?);"
```

Comment: You'll also need to capture the ID field from the articulo insert for use in the pedidodetalle  insert (assuming that field is DB generated.)

Answer (score 0):

Using transactions.

pseudo:

```
transaction.start();
insert 1;
insert 2;
insert 3;
transaction.commit();
```

I have no access to NetBeans right now to test this

Comment: If you're using plain JDBC, the transaction is managed by the connection object with `Connection#start`,`Connection#commit` and `Connection#rollback`